# parsing challenge with multiple string formats

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a device log, but the format is not consistent

Example:

```
Roam candidate# 9 F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F on channel 161  RSSI: -70

Roam candidate#10 F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F on channel 11  RSSI: -70
```

I want to pull the Mac address, the channel and the RSSI values
Unfortunately, the space is omitted after candidate value becomes 10 or higher.

I've tried to tokenize it, but I barely understand that process

```
def clean(string):
    result = ""
    for i,char in enumerate(line):
        if char == " ":
            if string[i+1].isdigit() or string[i+1] == " ":
                continue
        result += char
    return result

def tokenize(string):
    result = []
    previous = 0
    for i,char in enumerate(string):
        if char == " ":
            result.append(string[previous:i])
            previous = i+1
        elif i == len(string)-1:
            result.append(string[previous:i+1])
    return result
```

I only get the last column (RSSI) as output

Comment: Here's a regex that uses named capture groups. You can mouse-over things to find out what they do: https://regex101.com/r/0ALfov/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex it would work like this:

```
import re
s1="Roam candidate# 9 F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F on channel 161 RSSI: -70"
s2="Roam candidate#10 F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F on channel 11 RSSI: -70"

patt= re.compile('(?P<mac>[0-9A-F]{2}(:[0-9A-F]{2}){5}).*?channel (?P<channel>[0-9]*).*?RSSI:\s*(?P<rssi>-?[0-9]*)', re.I)

matcher= patt.search(s1)

print(matcher.group('mac'))
print(matcher.group('channel'))
print(matcher.group('rssi'))
```

This returns:

```
F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F
161
-70
```

And for the second line:

```
F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F
11
-70
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pattern, you could use 3 capturing groups, 1 for the mac address, 1 for the channel and 1 for the RSSI values:

```
Roam candidate# ?\d+ ((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]){2}) on channel (\d+) +RSSI: (-?\d+)
```

In smaller parts:

- `Roam candidate# ?\d+` Match *Roam candidate#*, optional space and 1+ digits
- `((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]){2})` Capture group 1, match mac address
- `on channel (\d+) +` Match *on channel*, space followed by capturing in group 2 1+ digits
- `RSSI: (-?\d+)` Match *RSSI:*, space and capture in group 3 an optional `-` and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKeVHv/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1nNq40)

For example

```
import re

strings = ["Roam candidate# 9 F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F on channel 161  RSSI: -70", "Roam candidate#10 F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F on channel 11  RSSI: -70"]
regex = r"Roam candidate# ?\d+ ((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]){2}) on channel (\d+) +RSSI: (-?\d+)"
for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(regex, s, re.M))
```

Result

> [('F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F', '161', '-70')]
>
> [('F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F', '11', '-70')]

Comment: in my case, I would need to pull many strings out of a log file. the values are from lines containing "constructNeighborCacheFromBeacon" thus I would filter on just those lines

Comment: @EricGarnel So you want to match the start literally https://regex101.com/r/vKeVHv/2

Answer (score 0):

Another regex approach:

```
import re

lines = '''Roam candidate# 9 F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F on channel 161  RSSI: -70
Roam candidate#10 F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F on channel 11  RSSI: -70'''

pat = re.compile(r'(?<=#)\s*\d+\s+((?:[A-F0-9]{2}:){5}[A-F0-9]{2}) .*channel\s+(\d+)\s+RSSI:\s+(-?\d+)', re.I)
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    print(pat.findall(line))
```

The output:

```
[('F4:CF:E2:5E:73:3F', '161', '-70')]
[('F4:CF:E2:62:02:2F', '11', '-70')]
```

Comment: This is exactly the output I'm looking for, but I'm stuck on how to read the just the lines containing a specific word into the array (in place of the lines statement in the example). Example lines with the word beaconcache in them.  Thanks

Comment: Here is how I solved it:       #!/usr/bin/python
# 
import sys, re


arr = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'constructNeighborCacheFromBeaconCache' in line:
#            print(line)
            arr.append(line)

regex = r"Roam candidate# ?\d+ ((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]){2}) on channel (\d+) +RSSI: (-?\d+)"
for s in arr:
    print(re.findall(regex, s, re.M))

Answer (score 0):

Something simple might be better

`r"(?i)([a-f0-9]{2}(?::[a-f0-9]{2})+)\s.*?\s(\d+)\s.*?\s(-?\d+)"`

https://regex101.com/r/smcjY5/1

Expanded

```
 (?i)
 (                             # (1 start)
      [a-f0-9]{2} 
      (?: : [a-f0-9]{2} )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s .*? \s 
 ( \d+ )                       # (2)
 \s .*? \s 
 ( -? \d+ )                    # (3)
```